# Recursion Pattern Matching, output issue

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use pattern matching and recursion to replace some words in a list with other words. The pattern matching does not work in all cases, and my code does not produce a list of strings changed, using pattern matching, in all cases.

I was wondering if someone can help me identify why this is?

```
pattr :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
pattr [] = []
pattr ("you":as) = ("u":pattr as)
pattr ("see":"you":as) = ("seaya":pattr as)
pattr ("by":"the":"way":as) = ("btw":pattr as)
pattr ("laugh":"out":"loud":as) = ("lol":pattr as)
pattr ("for":"your":"information":as) = ("fyi":pattr as)
pattr (x:as) = (x:as)
```

**Examples:**

```
GHCi> pattr ["milk", "see", "you", "soon"] 
> ["milk", "see", "you", "soon"] 
GHCi> pattr ["see", "you", "soon"]
> ["cya", "soon"]
```

Comment: You can drop the parentheses on the right hand side, e.g. `pattr ("you":as) = "u":pattr as`. On the left side, it needs to be parenthesized to be a single patternmatched argument, but on the right hand side it is just an expression, and doesn't change value whether you parenthesize or not. Also, it would be more usual to see `(x:xs)` instead of `(x:as)`. The first form implies that `x` is just the first of many similar elements (so `xs` is just the plural of `x`), while the second implies that `x` is somehow different from the rest of the list, which would seem to consist of a lot of `a`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you only need to change the last line:

```
pattr (x:as) = (x: pattr as)
```

Comment: Thank you! Did not catch that, recursion is a bit new me. I am still getting the hang of it;)

Answer (score 2):

You're not recursing in your last case. So if the first word in your list doesn't match any of the patterns, it just stops and doesn't check the words that come later in the list.